# How to show data of inner Array of JSON data using AJAX?

Tags: javascript, json, ajax, datatable

I have some sort of

```
[  
   {  
      "selectionId":1,
      "selectionDate":"101662",
      "selectedBy":"ABC",
      "eximPanNo":222,
      "eximPanName":"DEF",
      "eximPanNameEng":"KKK",
      "eximPanAddress":null,
      "eximPanAddressEng":null,
      "eximPanPhone":12334566,
      "selectionType":"G",
      "consignmentNo":0,
      "consignmentDate":"2098",
      "productName":"LLL",
      "selectionFromDate":"2019",
      "selectionToDate":"2090",
      "agentNo":123,
      "selectionStatus":"I",
      "entryBy":"PCS",
      "entryDate":"2018-11-22 11:46:02",
      "rStatus":"F",
      "custOfficeId":1,
      "selectionAudit":[  
         {  
            "audGrpId":1,
            "selectionId":1,
            "assignFromDate":"2075-08-03",
            "assignToDate":"2075-08-19",
            "entryBy":"1",
            "rStatus":"1"
         }
      ]
   }
]
```

How can i show this `selectionAudi.audGrpId` data in dataTable when called from AJAX?
Here the Api is called through AJAX.

```
var table = $('#nepal').DataTable({
            "processing" : true,
            "ajax" : {
                "url" : A_PAGE_CONTEXT_PATH + "/form/api/getAllSelectionAudit/all",
                dataSrc : ''
            },
            "columns" : [ {
                "data" : "selectionId"
            }, {
                "data" : "selectionDate"
            }, {
                "data" : "selectedBy"
            }, {
                "data" : "eximPanNo"
            } ]
        });
```

But when I add "data":"selectionAudi.audGrpId" then the datatable shows error like :
[image]

The code for table is:

```
<table id="nepal" class="table table-bodered">

          <thead>
            <tr>
              <th>Selection No</th>
              <th>SelectionDate</th>
              <th>SelectedBy</th>
              <th>PanEximNumber</th>
              <th>AudiGroupID</th>  


            </tr>
          </thead>
          <tbody>

          </tbody>

        </table>
```

How can i show the inner Json data into datatable?I am not able to see what is the real solution.

Comment: `selectionAudit` is an `array` with one `object` that has the `audGrpId` property, so you need `selectionAudi[0].audGrpId` to access the property.

Comment: because it's an array, I would recommend you to use the custom `render` callback, using the `data` or `row` argument and checking whether `selectionAudit` exists in your object. Check this for reference: https://datatables.net/reference/option/columns.render

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your problem is that `selectionAudit` is an `array` with one `object` that contains the `audGrpId` property, so writing just `selectionAudi.audGrpId` is what's throwing this Error, because it's trying to access the `audGrpId` property in the array.

What you need is to write `selectionAudit[0].audGrpId` to access the right property.

This is how should be your code:

```
var table = $('#nepal').DataTable({
        "processing" : true,
        "ajax" : {
            "url" : A_PAGE_CONTEXT_PATH + "/form/api/getAllSelectionAudit/all",
            dataSrc : ''
        },
        "columns" : [ {
            "data" : "selectionId"
        }, {
            "data" : "selectionDate"
        }, {
            "data" : "selectedBy"
        }, {
            "data" : "eximPanNo"
        }, {
            "data" : "selectionAudit[0].audGrpId"
         ]
});
```

**Note:**

This assumes `selectionAudit` is an `array` and it's always filled with this `object`.

Comment: Just a side note: this will fail if `selectionAudit` is an empty array. Not sure this will ever happen, but still...

Comment: @briosheje Yes, you are right, but  I assumed it's always like this.

Answer (score 0):

You can follow the way I usually do it not server side processing of datatable.

Suppose you HTML page from where you are making API calls -

```
<!-- Button to make API request -->
<button id="btnAPIRequest">API Request</button>

<!-- API response div -->
<div id="responseAPI"></div>
```

Call the API request through AJAX GET method and add below javascript code in bottom of your HTML page -

```
<script>
    $("#btnAPIRequest").click(function(){
        $.ajax({
            type: "GET",
            url: "Your/url/to/page.php",
            data: 'if you have any data else blank',
            dataType: 'json',
            success: function(data){
                if(data.success){
                    $("#responseAPI").html(data.message);

                    // Initialize datatable here
                }
                else{
                    $("#responseAPI").html(data.message);
                }
            }
        });
    });
</script>
```

Now in your php page where you actually calls the API and decode the json response -

```
<?php  
// Load the reuiqred library

// Make API request

// Get the resonse in json
$response = '[{"selectionId":1,..."selectionAudit":[{"audGrpId":1,..."rStatus":"1"}]}]';

// Decode the json response
$decoded_data = json_decode($response);

// Get your html table
$msg = '
    <table>
        <thead>
            <tr>
              <th>Selection No</th>
              <th>SelectionDate</th>
              <th>SelectedBy</th>
              <th>PanEximNumber</th>
              <th>AudiGroupID</th>  
            </tr>
          </thead>
          <tbody>
';

// Table body data
foreach($decoded_data as $data){
    $msg .= '
        <tr>
            <td>'.$data[0].'</td>
            <td>'.$data[2].'</td>
            <td>'.$data[3].'</td>
            <td>'.$data[4].'</td>
    ';

    // I think here you got stuck when extracting from multidimensional array
    foreach($data[n] as $audi_data){
        $msg .= '<td>'.$audi_data[i].'</td>';
    }

    $msg .=  '</tr>'; 
}

$msg .= '</tbody></table>';

// For success respone
// encode this value in json and ajax response will handle this as per return datatype option
echo json_encode(array('success'=>true, 'message'=>$msg));

// Similarly  for failed response
echo json_encode(array('success'=>true, 'message'=>$msg));

?>
```